# Python 3 Tkinker Multi threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

I have tired implementing other's threading for my very basic tkinker search GUI but, out of the various implementations I have attempted, none of them worked for me. The search function take some time to search through all the directories, and is successful. But, after the OS window opens with the correct directory, my tkinker GUI is hung-up and useless. This is my first time using multi-threading, thank you in advance.

```
"""
Script lunches GUI with text field and search button
Text field arg = WR # string
Search button event = calls Search
Search func looks in F:/WEST/* and F:/NORTH/* directories for WR # directory
Search func gets WR # directory
Search func opens WR # directory window in OS
"""

#Libaries
from tkinter import *
import glob
import os
import threading
import time
from queue import *


def search():
    """
    Searchs through NORTH and WEST directories
    Finds folder paths recursively with WR number at end of path name
    Calls os.startfile to Open the folder
    :return:NULL
    """
    wrNumber = e1.get()
    northPath   = 'F:/NORTH/**/**/**/**/*'
    westPath    = 'F:/WEST/**/**/**/**/*'

    for folderName in glob.iglob(westPath + str(wrNumber), recursive=True) \
                or glob.iglob(northPath + str(wrNumber), recursive=True):
        print(folderName)
        print(str(wrNumber))

        os.startfile(str(folderName))


#Initializes basic GUI window elements
master = Tk()

#Create GUI Title = 'WR# Searcher'
master.title("WR# Searcher")

#Create Label e1 = 'WR#'
Label(master, text="WR #", ).grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

#Create Button Button = 'Search'
Button(master, text='Search', command=search).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to thread anything? You import the threading module and things you need for it (queue), but you never do any threading.Thread et al.

Comment: I think the issue is more likely that `os.startfile` is not returning once the application is opened (which is what it is suppose to do) try testing it without tkinter and see if the program still hangs.

Comment: @Delioth The threading and queue libaries were left in after I removed my threading implementation code. I have tired multiple different implementations for the threading. I didn't think it would be constructive to post them all here. Since this is my first threading attempt, I do not know which implementation would be best.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The os.startfile returns properly, I believe. It executes the correct behavior, and if I put a print statement after the os.startfile function call, the print executes.

Comment: I found a clever solution to my problem. I instead inserted "master.destroy()" after I call wrNumber = e1.get().

That way the GUI ends, and the function still executes properly. Sadly, this doesn't allow me to reuse the GUI. I believe threading would be the best implementation, so that the GUI is re-usable for multiple search attempts.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen ....You're completely correct. The program never stops running after os.startfile finishes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module

Comment: @Delioth turns out my os.startfile() function returns correctly. A 'break' was needed in my for loop, it never exited. Thanks for all the help. If anyone has recommendations for threading this script, I would love to hear them.

Comment: The only real suggestion I have is: Don't use threading unless there is a good reason.  Assuming `os.startfile` just starts a file there is no reason it would block the GUI on a single thread program.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen from what I have read. It is the execution of the glob.iglob function that hangs the GUI. Since I am searching a large amount of directories, the process takes some time to execute. From what I have read, Tkinker is single threaded, and if it cannot run a process after a certain amount of time, in this case because the glob.iglob function is executing, then the GUI hangs.